# How can I create a list of files to pass to an executable using a DOS batch file?

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, batch-file, dos

I want to get a (semi-colon separated) list of all .dll and .exe in a directory as a variable to pass as an argument to an executable. I've tried a few things but it never quite works as expected. I've got part way there - the following prints out a list of the files I'm after:

```
CLS
@ECHO OFF
SET INPUT_FILES=
for /f %%x in ('dir /b E:\Builds\MyProgram\Release\*.exe E:\Builds\MyProgram\Release\*.dll') do ECHO %%x
```

...but the next step isn't quite right and I'm struggling to work out what I've got wrong:

```
CLS
@ECHO OFF
SET INPUT_FILES=
for /f %%x in ('dir /b E:\Builds\MyProgram\Release\*.exe E:\Builds\MyProgram\Release\*.dll') do IF DEFINED INPUT_FILES SET INPUT_FILES=INPUT_FILES;%%X ELSE SET INPUT_FILES=%%X
ECHO %INPUT_FILES%
```

I'm going to pass `%INPUT_FILES%` as an input to another executable if I can work out how to fix the issue here.

**Edit**

If I do the following commands, I can update the INPUT_FILES variable:

```
IF "%INPUT_FILES%"=="" (SET INPUT_FILES=Test1) ELSE (SET INPUT_FILES=Test1a)
IF "%INPUT_FILES%"=="" (SET INPUT_FILES=Test2) ELSE (SET INPUT_FILES=%INPUT_FILES%;Test2a)
ECHO %INPUT_FILES%
```

..which outputs:

```
Test1;Test2a
```

..but if I try and add that into the `FOR` loop I get nothing:

```
CLS
REM @ECHO OFF
SET INPUT_FILES=
for /f %%X in ('dir /b E:\Builds\MyProgram\Release\*.exe E:\Builds\MyProgram\Release\*.dll') do (IF "%INPUT_FILES%"=="" (SET INPUT_FILES=%%X) ELSE (SET INPUT_FILES=%INPUT_FILES%;%%X))
ECHO %INPUT_FILES%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the expansion of the percent variable.
These are expanded in the moment of parsing (also for blocks).

Better use delayed expansion, the syntax is nearly the same, but with `!variable!` instead of `%variable%`.
The difference is: The expansion occurs at execution time not at parsing time.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "INPUT_FILES="
for /f %%X in ('dir /b E:\Builds\*.exe E:\Builds\*.dll') do (
  IF "!INPUT_FILES!"=="" (
    SET "INPUT_FILES=%%X"
  ) ELSE (
    SET "INPUT_FILES=!INPUT_FILES!;%%X"
  )
)
ECHO !INPUT_FILES!
```

Comment: Awesome - I'd seen the exclamation marks in an example before but didn't have the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` line so they weren't evaluating properly.

Comment: You may avoid the `IF` command if just add each name followed by a semicolon, and eliminate the last semicolon at end: `for /f %%X in ('dir ...') do SET "INPUT_FILES=!INPUT_FILES!%%X;"` and `SET INPUT_FILES=!INPUT_FILES:~0,-1!`